# mysql query to get a related column

Tags: php, mysql

hoping you guys can help me with this, im still new to sql and figuring it out.

i have built a page using PHP that `$_GET` the unique id to display a record.

on this page, i would like to display all the records that share a specific column.

for example

php gets the unique id which is 44.

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = 44 -- (the problem)
```

get the data (ie racing) from id = 44 column cat_02
now display all of the product titles that are in cat_02 which are 'racing'

i hope that made sense.

Comment: post your complete query code

Comment: i know most of this isnt sql but hopefully it helps get through what im trying to achieve 
                    

$query = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = $id AND WHERE THE SELECTED $id = cat_02 DISPLAY ALL OF THE prod_titles IN cat_02 ";

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a connection to your database
2. Create a prepared statement with you query
3. Execute the statement providing you parameter
4. Loop through the results of the execution

Example:

```
    // creates a new PDO connection, you'll need to modify this to work with whatever DB you are using
    $dbh =  new PDO('mysql:host='.$host_name.';dbname='.$database, $username, $password);

    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT cat_02 FROM products WHERE id = ?"); // selects just the cat_02 column that has the product titles
    if ($stmt->execute(array($_GET['id']))) { // uses the id variable from $_GET
      while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) { // loops through all of the rows returned from the query
        print_r($row); // do what ever you wanted to with the row of results
      }
    }
```

Comment: that makes perfect sense. i thought i would have to do the entire query in sql.  thank you!